# How to merge some static data with json encode mysql array data?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to merge a static data with json encode array data for output. Here is my php code:

```
$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, picture, mail, gender, birthday FROM users WHERE id='$logged_id' ");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
   $arr[] = $obj;
}

echo '{"users":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

Now I want to merge other data with it:

```
$user_ip = array("user_ip" => $user_ip_address);
```

I have tried array_merge($arr, $user_ip). But it didn't work. I think this is not correct json array format if I merge with existing data array. Please let me know what to do how to output other data as well as current data coming from mysql with json encode.

I am getting such output with my existing code, which is correct:

**{"users":[{"id":"14","name":"Sonu Roy","picture":"image012.jpg","mail":"myemail@gmail.com","gender":"Male","birthday":"1983-01-11"}]}**

But now I want to add other variable e.g $user_ip_address as user's data joining with current output data like this:

**{"users":[{"id":"14","name":"Sonu Roy","picture":"image012.jpg","mail":"myemail@gmail.com","gender":"Male","birthday":"1983-01-11",user_ip:"127.0.0.1"}]}.**

I want to get it in this way. How to do it? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo json_encode(array('users' => $arr, 'user_ip' => $user_ip_address));
```

on a side note:
you should use PHP PDO class to connect and query the database.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_object` returns an object, not an array. So, what are you doing by `$arr[] = $obj;` is just adding an object into an array. So, the actual structure of the `$arr` is something like

```
$arr => [
    [0] => Object(....),
    [1] => Object(....),
    ....
]
```

In your particular case, I assume you are fetching single row by primary key, so there are only one object.

THe simpliest way to fix this is to add a field to an object. I haven't worked with PHP since 5.3, so can't be sure, but it's as simple as adding

```
$obj->user_ip = $user_ip_address;
```

inside the loop.

Btw, a couple of questions for you:

1. Why do you use loop if it should result in a single row?
2. Why you are embedding the variable directly into SQL query. It's quite vulnerable, read about sql-injections and how to prevent it (one day I was really tired telling people here on SO to use PDO and prepared statements, so just go read about it),
3. Have you read the documentation about `mysql_fetch_object` and `array_merge`? Why not (because if you have read it you wouldn't be asking the question).
4. Tried debugging? E.g. attaching a debugger and watching for variables contents? Inserting logging or (God forgive me) debug print with `echo`?
5. "Didn't work" is a quite bad error description. This time you was lucky, because the error was obvious. Next time, please, be more specific.

Comment: {"users":[{"id":"14","name":"Sonu Roy","picture":"image012.jpg","mail":"myemail@gmail.com","gender":"Male","birthday":"1983-01-11"}]}. I am getting such output with my existing code, which is correct.  But now I want to add other variable e.g $user_ip_address as user's data joining with current output data like this:  {"users":[{"id":"14","name":"Sonu Roy","picture":"image012.jpg","mail":"myemail@gmail.com","gender":"Male","birthday":"1983-01-11",user_ip:"127.0.0.1"}]}.